# Qual é diferença entre usar as propriedades dropEffect e effectAllowed?

Tags: javascript

O **MDN Web Docs** especifica o que as duas propriedades fazem:

**effectAllowed**

> A DataTransfer.effectAllowed propriedade especifica o efeito permitido para uma operação de arrastar. A operação de cópia é usada para indicar que os dados que estão sendo arrastados serão copiados do seu local atual para o local do drop. A operação de movimentação é usada para indicar que os dados que estão sendo arrastados serão movidos e a operação de link é usada para indicar que alguma forma de relacionamento ou conexão será criada entre os locais de origem e de largada. [Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/effectAllowed)

**dropEffect**

> A DataTransfer.dropEffect propriedade controla o feedback (normalmente visual) que o usuário recebe durante uma operação de arrastar e soltar. Isso afetará o cursor exibido ao arrastar. Por exemplo, quando o usuário passa o mouse sobre um elemento de destino, o cursor do navegador pode indicar qual tipo de operação ocorrerá. [Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect)

Mas o que acontece é que se eu utilizar tanto valores como `move`, `copy`, `link`, `none` que ambas as duas propriedades possuem, elas vão retornar o mesmo resultado que é mudar o cursor para um determinado ícone ou não permitir a queda do elemento arrastável dependendo do valor definido.

No exemplo abaixo tanto faz eu utilizar `effectAllowed` ou `dropEffect` com o valor definido para `none` o resultado vai ser o mesmo no qual o elemento arrastável não pode ser descartado:

**Exemplo:**

```js
let drag = document.querySelector("#drag");
let drop = document.querySelector("#drop");

drag.ondragstart = (event) => {
  event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "none"; // Comente essa e habilita a outra.
  event.dataTransfer.setData("example", event.target.id);
}

drop.ondragover = (event) => {
  // event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
  event.preventDefault();
}

drop.ondrop = (event) => {
  let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("example");
  event.target.appendChild(document.querySelector(`#${data}`));
}
```

```css
#drag,
#drop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#drag {
  background: #dddddd;
}

#drop {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag" draggable="true"></div>
<div id="drop"></div>
```

Qual seria a diferença entre usar ambas as propriedades mencionadas sendo que usando qualquer uma o resultado é o mesmo?

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição de como utilizar a parte do exemplo minimo em javascript, cada um tem a sua parte como está especificado na tela.

Comment: Valeu pela observação eu tinha esquecido!

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas suas perguntas tem várias assim, mais fica como exemplo para as próximas

Comment: Beleza! da próxima faço melhor :)